# Export ditaa diagram quietly in org-mode

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

I'm trying to automate the process of project compilation. Part of it uses org files. When an org file has a section like:

```
#+begin_src ditaa :file integration.png :cmdline -r -s 0.8 
<some diagram>
#+end_src
```

then it will try to interact when exporting it and fail. My compilation command looks more or less like this:

```
emacsclient -e "(progn (package-initialize)
          (require 'js2-mode) (require \'typescript)
          (require \'htmlize) 
          (setq org-ditaa-jar-path (expand-file-name 
          "~/.emacs.d/ditaa/ditaa0_9.jar\\"))
          (org-babel-do-load-languages 
          'org-babel-load-languages '((ditaa . t)))
          (find-file "$some-org-file") (org-export-as-html 3)
          (org-export-as-odt 3))"
```

When I export the file interactively, it works, but non-interactively, the files are jumbled. Any idea on how to automatically answer "yes" to ditaa export prompt?

Thanks Rachel Gallen for the answer. Just to make this answer complete:

```
#+BIND: org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil
```

this is the variable which has to be set in order for the export to proceed silently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following setting :

```
  #+BIND
```

allows variables to be set on export without confirmation. For situations where you want to override some org-mode variable for export,  this allows exporting the document without a prompt.

example:

```
  (setq org-export-allow-BIND t)
```

[Source](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#SpeedCommands) (an interesting read!)

Comment: I shall update the link later. I'm on a train at the moment. I think you're right.